# What is a proper way of uninstalling field types provided by the module?

Tags: 8

I have a field type named `mymodule_field_type`, and we are installing it with
    `config/install/field.storage.node.mymodule.yml`, which has the following content:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - mymodule
    - node
id: node.mymodule
field_name: mymodule
entity_type: node
type: mymodule_field_type
settings: {  }
module: mymodule
locked: true
cardinality: 1
translatable: false
indexes: {  }
persist_with_no_fields: true
custom_storage: false
```

This field type has `no_ui` set, it's supposed to be automatically attached to the chosen content type. But it is also supposed to be completely uninstalled if module is uninstalled.

What is the proper way of solving this? The issue seems to be that whatever I do, I cannot uninstall this module, because there is this message that field type is being used in the field `node.[field_name]`.

The issue is that this problem has to be solved in order to even make the module uninstallable, so I'm effectively unable to uninstall it. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: I would check what a Drupal core module does, for example in [field.storage.node.taxonomy_forums.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21forum%21config%21optional%21field.storage.node.taxonomy_forums.yml/8.8.x). The differences I can see are the directory where the YAML file is stored and the value for *persist_with_no_fields*. Since the Forum module is uninstallable, those differences could be what makes... the difference. I am not sure there is something else that makes the Forum module uninstallable; that is the reason I am not posting this as answer.

Comment: For what I recall, putting a configuration file in config/optional makes the field optional, which means the field can be removed when the module is uninstalled. Putting the configuration file in config/install causes problems when the module is uninstalled and then re-installed.

Comment: Have you tried `hook_uninstall` in this module's `.install` file to delete the field programmatically?

Comment: `hook_uninstall` won't even run because this issue blocks uninstallation as a whole.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Interestingly changing both these things didn't help, I'm looking into this module though, I hope there is something.

Comment: I think for now I will just manually remove the `FieldStorageConfig` with the last field, and create it with the first created field. This question is very much open if anyone knows how to solve it better.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Look at this: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/modules/forum/forum.install#L51-53 I think it might be an actual issue with the core, because in my case, I'm at the same time field type provider and consumer, so I cannot uninstall myself like it is being done in the `forum` module. It might be that removing manually the `FieldStorageConfig` in the same place where the last field is being removed, is the only way for now :( .